# How to rate-limit my calls to an external API?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rate-limiting

With Spring I am trying to rate-limit my calls to an external API that I need to call once in 15 seconds and these calls will be triggered based on a specific event and the number of these calls is not fixed at all.

I have come across the `Guava RateLimiter` and the `Bucket4j` but both of them are based on the Token-bucket Algorithm and I do think they are useful to this business case as I think I should be using the leaky bucket algorithm to do so.

Comment: How about checking in the event handler - if last call not older then 15 sec - ignore.

Comment: I assume you mean "... I do _not_ think they are useful..."

Comment: I can not Ignore any calls it is the core business

Comment: Mhmm. But you will eventually receive more events then you are allow to send. If not ignore then postpone for the rest time of the 15 sec period.

Comment: Exactly, that is my question, how to postpone !! using a specific library or implementing a specific structure

Answer (score 0):

These APIs use the token bucket algorithm, but they allow you to block instead of dropping the packet. That way, you can easily implement your own leaky bucket algorithm based on these APIs.

Start a thread that uses a concurrent queue for receiving API requests. Then this thread attempts to forward the request to the external API, if the rate limiter allows, or have the rate limiter block the thread until the required time passes, then the thread sends the request.

Comment: So basically you are saying to use one of these libraries with a bucket of 1 token?

Comment: Yes, 1 token that is replenished every 15 seconds.